# Start Session into Laravel with user id from another framework

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I pass the user id from another framework to Laravel.

How can i start a Laravel 5.1 Session with this user id?

So the user will be logged in into Laravel coming from another framework login.

My method to receive the user id :

```
public function user( $user_id )
{
      Auth::loginUsingId($user_id);
      //echo Auth::check($user_id);
      return view('mymethod.index');
}
```

I found this way below, but does not know if Session::has('user') will work after this :
`$request->session()->put('key', 'value');`

And i check on templates/master.blade.php with:
    `@if( !\Session::has('user')`

How do i create the session user object after using `Auth::loginUsingId($user_id);`

Comment: How are you passing the user id to Laravel form the other framework? Are you redirecting the user to Laravel or is this with the initial login of the other framework and use may visit the Laravel app later?

Comment: I am using the PHP header function into CakePHP right into webroot/index.php, before Dispatcher. And receiving into Laravel routes. Them into a Laravel Controller i try to force the login using :  `Auth::loginUsingId($user_id);` . I think now i would need to create the user session, so i can use the Session´s methods like : Session::has('user')

Comment: It is a migration from CakePHP 2.5.2 to Laravel so route by route, module by module will be migrated from CakePHP

Comment: This line: $request->session()->put('user', $user ); trigger this error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::session() but i pass Requst $request as a parameter how can i fix it ?

Comment: What happens if you try {{ Auth::user()->name }} in your blade file. I'm not sure user is set to the session unless you are specifically assigning it.

Comment: Also I'm not sure about the session method being on the request what if you sue the fascade `Session::put('key', 'value');`.

Comment: Auth::user()->name is set. Also i specify a session with `$request->session()->put('user', $user );`

Comment: After all i solved passing the user id from CakePHP route and into Laravel using:   `if ( \Auth::loginUsingId( $userid ) )
                {
  $request->session()->put('user', $user ); ...`